# Moving a file from a remote server using CGI script

Tags: apache, shell, cgi

This is what I need

I have a local server hosting some CGI shell scripts. I have a file in remote server. I want my CGI script to copy the file from my remote server to local server.

This is what I tried

To avoid entering password every time, I created key file using ssh-keygen command and copied my public key file to remote server /root/.ssh/authorised_keys file and it worked. Whenever I execute scp user@remotehost:/root/ . intended file is copied to my local server without any manual authentication and this works perfect.

Now, I want the same thing for apache user which triggeres the CGI Script. I used below command to generate a key file for apache user

```
sudo -u _apache ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

and system response is

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/Library/WebServer/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Normally my .ssh keys are stored in location /root/.ssh and why system my command is defaulting to /Library/WebServer ? Can I have two .ssh files?

Is there any other solution than what I am trying?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every user in the system should have his/her own ~/.ssh directory.

When ssh runs, it will look for the .ssh directory in the user's home directory. You can check what is the a user's home directory from /etc/passwd or with the finger utilty. When reading /etc/passwd the home directory is the second from the end. For example:

```
postgres:x:106:115:PostgreSQL administrator,,,:/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash
```

In this case, the home directory is /var/lib/postgresql

To solve your problem, if you are not going to use your ssh for anything else, you can just copy your id_rsa key from the first user to the .ssh directory of the second user (changing user ownership and keeping the file chmod go-rwx).

Or you can just generate a new key like you did, and then append the new .ssh/id_rsa to the remote .ssh/authorized_keys.

Beware that the first method will have two users sharing the same RSA key, and please note that you should really not have the root user on the remote machine having an authorized key that can be used from within a  CGI script. Both are securty risks. It would be better to create a non-priviledged user on the remote machine and use it to transfer the file.